# How to display NSArray data fetched from web in scrollview and expand+update it in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I fetched some data from the web and the string data is stored in NSArray as shown below:

```
"Player one:",
"\n Score:",
"5667",
"3445",
"0233",
"\n Game Name:",
"Super Mario Bros",
"Monster in my house",
"Jackle"
```

The data will showup on screen like this:

```
        **Player One**

Score:            Game Name:

5667              Super Mario Bros
3445              Monster in my house
0233              Jackle
```

I've tried putting blank label on UIView and UIScrollView as well. So when the "Score" is updated it overwrite the UILabel value. But there are maximum 10 players (like the above player) data I want to display on the screen, if the users are online. That means there could be only one user scoreboard or there can be 5 or 10 user scoreboards displayed on the screen.

So, the problem is that how can I make the scrollview to expand or shrink depending on how much data I'm displaying on the screen. And where should I put the blank UILabels so scollview won't display empty long white page? is there any way to do this? I've tried putting UILabels but it's not the perfect solution as I'm having this problem of having unnecessary long white page.

In short, is there any way I can display this data and auto expand and shrink the scrollview? or is there any better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can put a UITableView inside UIScrollView and set it's height:

```
   [[self yourTableView] setFrame:CGRectMake(yourTableView.frame.origin.x,0, yourTableView.frame.size.width, 50 *yourArray.count)]; //let's say your cell's height is 50
```

//   yourArray.count reflects how many rows you will have based on your online users number

Every cell (row) will contain one online player. You can add custom cell for more user'friendly design :D

Use the above method every time you are updating your datasource (array) and let your UIScrollView also reflect those modification:

```
   [yourScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(yourScrollView.size.width, yourTableView.frame.origin.y + yourTableView.frame.size.height+35 )]; //let's say we add just 35 as white space...
```